# Unable to Launch Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am trying to run unit tests on our CI server. When i run the following command it tries to launch emulator but fails with the following message

```
vstest.console.exe myxapfile.xap
```

Error Message

```
The Windows Phone Emulator wasn't able to ensure the virtual machine was running:

Something happened while starting a virtual machine: 'Emulator WVGA 512MB.ttmaltiparmak' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 1350ADCE-CC35-4615-BFD5-250179F789EE)

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'Emulator WVGA
512MB.ttmaltiparmak' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID
1350ADCE-CC35-4615-BFD5-250179F789EE).
```

My system seems to support following requirements (But it is a virtual machine is it a problem?)

- 64 bit windows 8
- SLAT Support
- 4 GB ram
- Hyper-V is on

***Further trials and results:***

I tried removing and re-adding hyper-v through add-remove programs and now **Hyper-V Platform** option is disabled and i can not activate it :S Gilson Banin  says that hyper-v installation is not possible on virtual machines, as i mentioned before our server is a virtual machine is it right that i cant use hyper-v on a virtual machine?

http://blogs.technet.com/b/gbanin/archive/2013/06/26/how-to-install-hyper-v-on-a-virtual-machine-in-hyper-v.aspx

[image]

**The answer given on MSDN**: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/083c8964-071f-469a-8740-2412a69092fc/unable-to-launch-windows-phone-emulator?forum=wptools

Comment: Are you able to start the VM using Hyper-V or the developer tools if you have them installed? It is probably a configuration problem.

Comment: No, I cant even launch it using Visual Studio, it gives the same error.

Comment: what version of Windows is installed? it should be Pro or higher

Comment: windows 8 enterprise 64 bit

Comment: Can you run _any_ VM in Hyper-V ?

Comment: just created an empty virtual machine and it does not start too. Error is same. it seems this is completely a hyper-v problem.

Comment: Did you check the BIOS option already? Does the HV manager say "stop service" or "start service" ?

Comment: yes i checked bios and i can start-stop the hyper-v service but it did not help.

Comment: The version of Visual Studio and service pack may be more important.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem. This fixed it.

Shut down the VM, select option “Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or ARM-V/RVI” in the vm processor settings.

Then add these two lines to the end of the vmx-file:

```
hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"
mce.enable = "TRUE"
```

Start the VM, add the Hyper-V components and restart the vm. Next time you start the emulator, Visual Studio will configure Hyper-V and run the emulator

Comment: This did it for me, too. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/12/21/how-to-develop-for-windows-phone-8-on-your-mac.aspx. Mac + VMWare Fusion ofc.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've successfully fixed this issue. But I've my particular scenario, so I don't know if it can solve for you too. My scenario is as follow:

1. I'm developing for Windows Phone 8, using a iMac 10.9.1 OSX;
2. I'm using the VMWare Fusion 6, with Windows 8.1 imported through bootcamp;
3. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, running the emulator from it;
4. I was receiving that error in every manner that I used to launch the Windows Phone Emulator.

To fix the issue:

1. You must use Hyper-V (VM Settings -> Processors & Memory -> Advanced options -> [Enable hypervisor applications in this virtual machine] must be checked), only changeable with VMWare turned off;
2. To use Hyper-V, your VMWare must have at least 2 processors. It can be set with VMWare turned off in the same window of item 1;
3. In VM Settings -> Advanced -> Preferred virtualization engine, select Intel VT-x with EPT;
4. Open the directory where you VMWare image is located, and open it with [option] button holded. Click in [Show Package Contents] and locate the .vmx file. Open this file with a text editor and put/modify these lines:

   - `hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"`
   - `mce.enable = "TRUE"`
   - `vhv.enable = "TRUE"`
5. I've followed these references:

   - [http://blogs.msdn.com/](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/12/21/how-to-develop-for-windows-phone-8-on-your-mac.aspx)
   - [http://girliemac.com/](http://girliemac.com/blog/2013/01/09/how-to-enable-wp8-emulator-on-mac/?utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=bufferc6e4d)

I hope that it helps you too!

Comment: I had to leave off vhv.enable = True, otherwise my vm would report and error. I am using VMWare Fusion 6.0.5. See post above this one.

Comment: Do you know how can fix this in virtualbox ?

Comment: @Max, did you got the solution for vBox? I'm facing the same.

Answer (score 1):

After enabling support for VTx in your BIOS, you might want to check your system by running the [Codeinfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722) tool.

Also, don't forget to enable "Hyper-V Management Tools" and "Hyper-V Platform" on "Control Panel->Programs and Features->Turn Windows Features on of off->Hyper-V":

I am running Windows 8 64 bit inside VMware player on top of a windows 7 machine. Also had problems running the emulator from windows phone 8, and solved them by following this guide: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

You have not installed Hyper-V properly. "Hyper-V platform" should be installed for the service to run. Normally VM's have a "**hypervisor**" running by default and Hyper-V requires this hypervisor to run itself.

So first **disable the hypervisor** of the VM by altering the "vmx"(in case its vmware) file of your virtual machine(BACK UP THE FILE BEFORE MAKING CHANGES!)

> off your VM
>
> locate the .vmx file

If you cant fiond the vmx file read this article  - http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003880

> open it with notepad and add this
> line at the end(or anywhere actually)
>
> hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"

If you cant find the vmx file read this article
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003880

> Now you will be able to install the "Hyper-V platform" in windows
> "turn windows features on or off", do that.
>
> restart

Try deploying to WP Now! If it is still not working please comment the error you get!

Answer (score 0):

Select the Emulator VM you are going to use in Windows 8 Phone development 
(default one is “Emulator WVGA 512MB”). Go to the **Hyper-V VM settings** and change the **number of processors** from **2 to 1**. Press Apply and than OK in order to apply new settings.

If on a Mac or virtual machine ..

Or try to see the other solutions in this link:

[Running Windows 8 Phone emulator in the Windows 8 virtual machine Problem](http://kb.parallels.com/en/115211)

I really hope this link link can help you a less ;-)

Comment: Thanks Mehdi, i was hoping that your solution would work but it did not, still giving the same error. Do you know what are the hyper-v components? how can i find the one that is not running.

Comment: Mhh sorry .. How many processor, and memory you have allocated to your virtual machine ? Otherwise it is the latter, I can give you is to launch the repair tool "Visual Studio" from the Control Panel "Add / Removed"

Comment: i tried that also but for the second time i cant turn Hyper-v Platform on. You can see the question for details i updated it with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your vhd and other files from the vhd location to another folder. Just create another a new VM with the VHD which you just copied. Now it will start.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where I had installed an azure component which preceded the current Visual Studio quarterly update and caused the emulator to die.

I recommend that you re-install/fix the current Visual Studio Update. Reboot and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select the option “Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or ARM-V/RVI”. This is required to be able to run HYPER-V on your virtual machine.

Comment: this is not hte correct way to answer,do read FAQ to know how to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just open Hyper-V manager and delete all connections. Then try again. This solution worked on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines to the end of the vmx-file:

hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"
mce.enable = "TRUE"

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on **Computer** --> Click **Properties** --> On Left Look for "**Advanced System Properties**" and Click on it Click "**Advanced**" tab --> Click the "**Performance Setting**" Button --> Click "**Advanced**" Tab --> In the "**Virtual Memory**" section Click "**Change ..**" --> **Unchecked Automatically manage paging file size for all drives** --> Click Radio **Custom size** --> Set the values manually - **Minimum [4096], Maximum [8192]**