# Windows Phone 8 Emulator is not running. It was running before uninstall the Oracle Virtual Machine

Tags: visual-studio-2012, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am working in windows phone 8 app. My windows phone 8 emulator was working properly but it stopped working when i installed the Oracle Virtual Machine for learn something by it but when i tested my windows phone app than app was successfully build but Windows phone 8 emulator was not loading. Than what i did, i opened Hyper-V Manager and started emulator and kept the checkpoints during running emulator. My checkpoint Steps i am writing .

1) Windows icon visible and took 2 minutes to invisible.

2) Blank screen visible continuously.

3) It automatically closed.

I tried to run wp8 emulator from my app as well as Hyper-V manager many times. But all wasted. :(. Need helpful suggestion and solution to resolve it.

Comment: Easy fix, unistall the Oracle Virtual Box and reinstall the WP8 SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,  I have uninstalled oracle virtual machine already. But did not try uninstall wp8 sdk. Have tried this approach work for you?  I am asking to save my hours. But I try this too.

Comment: Type Winkey and write "activate" and open the Windows resources and check the "Hyper-V" checkbox.

Comment: @NickeDaSilvaManarin i am unable to understand your answer i feel its much brief. So please explore your answer by which i will be able to understand and resolve my issue.

Comment: Ok, sorry. There is a system tool, that ables you to activate and deactivate the Windows features. Follow the first 2 steps, here: http://devtunes.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/how-to-activate-default-games-in.html and search for the Hiper-V.

Comment: @NickeDaSilvaManarin ok, now i have tested with my machine Hyper-V is already checked and as you mentioned "Windows Resources" this i have not found in my machine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46424/discussion-between-ashish-jain-and-nicke-da-silva-manarin)

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824822.aspx#BKMK_answer

                      I have found above link. Please search by following string.
'To enable or disable Windows features by using DISM and an answer file'

Comment: Should Me try to repair Visual Studio 2012 ?

Comment: Yep. Or just repare the SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly me should not say its answer. Because it was the last option for me. It was uncertainty that my problem will be solve or not but now its solved.I just uninstalled my WP8 SDK and re-installed and restarted my laptop its working fine now. Thank God, i wasted much time but i learned a lot about the Hyper-V during fixing this issue.