# Windows phone 8 Emulator is running successfully through Hyper-V Manager but not running by Visual Studio 2012

Tags: hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

Windows phone 8 Emulator is running from Hyper-V Manager Successfully. But when i am trying to test my successfully build windows phone 8 application from the Visual Studio 2012 the emulator runs having following messages.

1) **'Loading....'** than after few seconds message changes

2) **'The Windows Phone OS is starting...'** and it take little more time and emulator closes
    after showing the Following message.

3) **'The Windows Phone Emulator is shutting Down'**

Comment: Does the emulation device show up?

Comment: Yes, 
first message is 'Loading....',  
Second message is 'The Windows Phone OS is starting...'

Comment: Yes, 
first message is 'Loading....',  
Second message is 'The Windows Phone OS is starting...' and after taking long time having second message it shows third Error Message 'The Windows Phone Emulator is shutting Down'.

Comment: Should me try to repair Visual Studio 2012 ?

Comment: I have never tried it with 2012. I use 2013.. So I am not sure what the problem might be..

Comment: @Scrooj I have posted a question last week too regarding that i am pasting that link following. You can say following is the more exploration of my this question. Following question is also asked by me. I am stucked in this problem since last week.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431680/windows-phone-8-emulator-is-not-running-it-was-running-before-uninstall-the-ora

Comment: Okk.. so virtualbox.. I suggest you use VMware/parallels..I spent a day trying to get it work on my VM running on virtualbox.. for some reason there isn't enough support for virtualization.. its important because we would be running a VM in a VM.. But VMware was easy to get it working and install.. So that would be my bet

Comment: Actually what happened, i wanted to learn about the Oracle Virtual Box. So i installed in my machine. In mean time i tried my app after little modification as usual. But it did not run and behavior of emulator randomly changed so i thought it might be happened due to Oracle Virtual Machine. So i uninstalled the OVM. but error remained exist.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46661/discussion-between-scrooj-and-ashish-jain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly me should not say its answer. Because it was the last option for me. It was uncertainty that my problem will be solve or not but now its solved.I just uninstalled my WP8 SDK and re-installed and restarted my laptop its working fine now. Thank God.